# Decoding nested JSON with multiple 'for' loops

Tags: python, json, serialization, for-loop, nested

I'm new to Python (last week), and have reached my limit. Spent three days on this, most of my time in stackoverflow, but I cannot work out how to go any further!

The [Json](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3758695/json.txt) has multiple nested arrays. It could contain three (as the example below (json.txt) does), or 30. I need to loop through each, then drill down to 'innings' and finally get the value of 'wickets'. It's this last step that I'm confused by. Can anyone advise?

Yours in total desperation

Will

```
import os, json,requests
print 'Starting'
url = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3758695/json.txt'

# download the json string
json_string = requests.get(url)
print 'Downloaded json'

# get the content
the_data = json_string.json()
print 'the_data has length ', len(the_data)
for index in range(len(the_data)):
    print 'Now working on index ', index
    for wicket in the_data[index]:
            print 'wicket equals ',wicket
                    # OK - I can see Innings. Now, how do I get inside
                    # and obtain 'wickets'?
```

Comment: Are you saying that the depth of nesting could be 3 or 30, or that the number of arrays (which are all the same depth) could be 3 or 30? It might be helpful if you posted some examples of the json that you are trying to parse.

Comment: @MarkkuK.: the dropbox URL in the code is actually live. Not the best way to provide a sample, but that's how I was able to build my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, don't use an index but loop *directly* over the lists; that way you can give them meaningful names. The top-level is a list of entries, each entry is a dictionary with a `'innings'` key, and each `innings` is a list of dictionaries, with, among others, a `wickets` key:

```
for entry in data:
    for inning in entry['innings']:
        print inning['wickets']
```

This prints:

```
>>> for entry in data:
...     for inning in entry['innings']:
...         print inning['wickets']
... 
10
9
0
0
```

This makes it easier to add information at each level too:

```
>>> for entry in data:
...     print entry['description']
...     for i, inning in enumerate(entry['innings']):
...         print 'Innings {}: {} wickets'.format(i + 1, inning['wickets'])
... 
Rest of Sri Lanka v Sri Lanka A at Pallekele, May 14, 2013
Innings 1: 10 wickets
Innings 2: 9 wickets
63rd match: Royal Challengers Bangalore v Kings XI Punjab at Bangalore, May 14, 2013
Innings 1: 0 wickets
Innings 2: 0 wickets
64th match: Chennai Super Kings v Delhi Daredevils at Chennai, May 14, 2013
```

Comment: Martijn - hugely helpful. Thank you very much! It's a huge step forward for my understanding; I don't understand much of the second part yet. For example, "print 'Innings {}: {} wickets'.format(i + 1, inning['wickets'])" - the {} brackets. How will it include the innings first and wickets second? A lot of this seems to me like wizard magic!

Comment: @Will: All I did was add 2 `print` statements; the [`enumerate()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) adds a counter to the loop, and the [`str.format()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) is just a way to put some data into strings.

Comment: @Will: You can add numbers to the `{}` placeholders: `'Innings {0}: {1} wickets'`, but if you omit them, then Python 'counts' them for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os, json,requests
print 'Starting'
url = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3758695/json.txt'

# download the json string
json_string = requests.get(url)
print 'Downloaded json'

# get the content
the_data = json_string.json()
print 'the_data has length ', len(the_data)
for index in range(len(the_data)):
    print 'Now working on index ', index
    for d in the_data[index]['innings']:
        print d['wickets']
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks ugly, but you can refine this, but here is listing at arbitrary depth of mix of Dict and List:

```
import os, json,requests
print 'Starting'
url = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3758695/json.txt'

# download the json string
json_string = requests.get(url)
print 'Downloaded json'

def dig_down(partial_json_list, depth):
    if type(partial_json_list) is list:
        for i in range(len(partial_json_list)):
            print 'index', i, ' at depth', depth,' has', len(partial_json_list[i]) , 'elements'
            if len(partial_json_list[i]) > 1:
                dig_down(partial_json_list[i],depth+1)
    else:
        for k in partial_json_list:
            print 'item at depth', depth, 'equals', k#, ' & has', len(partial_json_list[k]) , 'elements'
            if type(partial_json_list) is list or type(partial_json_list) is dict:
                try:
                    if len(partial_json_list[k]) > 1:
                        dig_down(partial_json_list[k],depth+1)
                except:
                    pass
            else:
                print partial_json_list[k]

# get the content
the_data = json_string.json()
print 'the_data has length ', len(the_data)
dig_down(the_data,0)
```